# Sniff UDP port for presence of data without blocking it for other apps

Tags: c++, udp

from my application I whant to know if there is some data come to UDP port.
At the same time I don't want my application to block another application (VLC player) which listen to this UDP port.
I just want to know if there is any data comes.

I use VLC-broadcast UDP, and another VLC for receiving.

In my C++ application I tried to use select() for this, but after bind()'ing socket VLC stop displaing data.

Operating system is Windows.

Comment: I guess you could try to see what other software like tcpdump, wireshark or iptop does to detect traffic without interfering with applications.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode

Comment: This is a highly operating-system specific task. What OS are you targeting?

Comment: I use Windows. 
But could I do it without PCAP library with promiscuous mode?
I thought about this, but I was hoping that could do it without PCAP

Comment: WinPcap would have been my suggestion for windows. But I think you don't have to put the network adapter in promiscuous mode to do that. Promiscuous mode is only needed when you want to sniff packets sent to a different system in the same collision domain.